# How do i parse the following JSON object to retrieve relevant fields in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, tags

How do I parse the following JSON object to retrieve relevant fields like "name", "containing-group", etc... I am using python, and i need to extract the values for the given fields.

```
The JSON object is provided below.

{
-"com.response-message": {
-"com.header": {
"com.firstIndex": 0,
"com.lastIndex": 2
},
-"com.data": {
-"nd.group": [
-{
"nd.containing-group": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=All Locations",
"nd.description": "This is a location group",
"nd.fdn": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=System Campus",
"nd.name": "System Campus"
},
-{
"nd.containing-group": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=All Locations",
"nd.description": "This is a location group",
"nd.fdn": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=Unassigned",
"MD=CISCO_EPNM!ND=J_59.J_cisco.com",
"MD=CISCO_EPNM!ND=42_Head"
]
},
-{
-"nd.contained-group": [
"MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=Optical Networking",
"MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=Third Party Device"
],
"nd.description": "Device Type",``
"nd.fdn": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!GR=Device Type",
"nd.name": "Device Type"
}
]
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really have dash in the JSON before some keys?

Comment: why tag a python question with `javascript`?

Comment: This is not JSON data. Please use a JSON linter (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/for instance) to see where the problem is (the dashes, to start with)